# How to make a semi-circular movement?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, math, geometry

Suppose I have a car in position P0 and I want to move it to position P1, just like these 4 examples:

[image]

The linear distance between P0 and P1 is `d` and the perpendicular maximum height the movement reaches is `d/3`. I want to simulate this clockwise semi-circular movement from P0 to P1.

Suppose `dir = P1 - P0` (length `d`) and `perp` is the vector (of length `d/3`) perpendicular to `dir`.

Suppose `t = 0` is the beginning of the semi-circular movement and `t = 1` is the end, how can I measure the angle and the position of the car at `t = i`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have to find angle of this arc and circle center.

At first find radius.

```
R^2 = (d/2)^2 + (R-d/3)^2  //pythagorean
R = 13/24 * d
```

Now angle

```
half_angle = arcsin(12/13) ~ 67.4 degrees 
angle = 2 * half_angle ~ 135 degrees = 2.35 radians
```

Normalize perp vector

```
uperp = perp / len(perp)
```

Get circle center

```
M = (P0 + P1)/2   //chord middle
C = M + uperp * 5/24 * d
```

Starting angle

```
A0 = atan2(P0.Y-C.Y, P0.X-C.X)
```

And finally coordinates

```
Car.X = C.X + R * Cos(A0 + t * angle)
Car.Y = C.Y + R * Sin(A0 + t * angle)
```

In Unity this would look like:

```
Vector2 startPosition;
Vector2 endPosition;
Vector2 perp;
float t;

float d = (endPosition - startPosition).magnitude;

float radius = 13f/24f * d;
float angle = 2f * Mathf.Asin(12f/13f);

Vector2 uperp = perp.normalized;

Vector2 M = (startPosition+endPosition)*0.5f;
Vector2 C = M + uperp * 5f/24f * d;

float A0 = Mathf.Atan2(startPosition.y-C.y, startPosition.x-C.x);
float At = A0 + t * angle;

Vector2 newPos = C + radius * new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(At), Mathf.Sin(At));
```

[image]

Comment: What is `half_angle`?

Comment: Angle of half of arc - because I calculated it's sine as ratio of d/2 and R

Comment: Made better picture

Comment: At time `t = i`, will the car angle be `Ai = atan2(Pi.Y-C.Y, Pi.X-C.Y)` (where `Pi` is the car position)?

Comment: Yes, but there is no need to calculate this angle using this way - it is already known as `A0 + t * angle`. Note - this is angle of car position relative to arc/circle center. If you want to know car direction angle - add Pi/2

Comment: Mbo what did you use to draw the above graph ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Rex5  [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org)  (and I for some strange reason prefer older [5-th version](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Installation))

Comment: @Daniel I fixed a typo in the algorithm and added unity code since the question was tagged with unity (and is now tagged with C#)

Comment: As the car moves, its angle also changes, it is necessary to calculate the angle in the Update function

Comment: @Daniel The only inputs are `startPosition, endPosition, perp, and t` and only `t` changes as the car goes through the movement. And `t` only comes in at the last step in the calculation. You don't have to recalculate anything else unless a new turn (new `startPosition`/`endPosition`/`perp`) is beginning.